# Audio Files and Digital Bearer Instruments

Tags: public-key, data-privacy, digital-rights-management

Is it possible to combine Audio Files and Public Key Cryptography creating a Digital Bearer Audio File that is in complete control of the owner who would then have the ability to grant access to listening to the file, editing the file and sharing the file?

Comment: Why don't you use hybrid encryption? With it, the receiver can decrypt and do whatever he wants to the file!

Comment: Can the creator of the audio file use their private key to create permissions for the file? for example this userA can only play the file, this userB can play+edit, and userC can play+share. Thanks for your guidance, much appreciated!

Comment: Without a restricted environment this is impossible. If you let me play, I can save it at least from audio jack. If you let me edit it, I can save it and then share. You can insert some stenography into the audio source to distinguish the sharer, however this can be overcomed. So, what is the actual problem/product?

Comment: You're essentially asking for DRM, and that is provably never perfect for media files due to the analog hole

Comment: I'm interested in a platform for artist to create with each other and preferably I'd like for it to be an open environment. Im in the very early stages of my research. Thank You both for your input -- can you point me towards any resources you find value for learning about audio files, cryptography/encryption, distributed systems?